# htaccess for allowing domain to serve only images

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, seo

For the life of me I can't work this out.

I have one main domain, hosting a busy website. (domain1.com)

I have a second domain, which uses content from domain #1. To link the images on this second site I want to use images.domain2.com.

images.domain2.com has been set up as an alias on domain1.com.

So now if someone goes to images.domain2.com they see domain1.com content, I don't want people to see this. (duplicate content).

I want it to work though, if someone requests images.domain2.com/images/image1.jpg.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^images\.domain2\.com [NC] 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domain2.com/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Not understanding the css reference though? Does this restrict access to all files unless jpg/png?

Comment: Updated it. I thought you only have to allow css files. I misread it!

Comment: It works, but i get an internal 500 error if I don't request an image file, is there a way to give a clean 404 error? Or something that needs changing to prevent a 500 error? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Now goes into a redirect loop. So images.domain2.com now goes to images.domain.com/domain2.com

Comment: sorry, better you redirect to some 404 page. create a 404.html page in the same folder where .htaccess reside. RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.html [L]